# Deploying Windows application with SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I have a WPF project and I will use SQL Server database. The instance of SQL Server IT created for me is SQL Server 13 (2016 standard version) on a remove server. When I’m deploying the application on a client’s computers, what version I need to install there as a prerequisite? Can I deploy SQL Server Express 2016 on a client’s computer and access the remove SQL Server Standard edition? I am looking for a simple solution and for a lighter version I need to install on the user’s computers. I cannot install a full SQL Server on each user.

Comment: Have you tested the configuration as it will be deployed? that'll be step #1

Comment: Have you tried deploying the application first on your client's machine and see if it works? Generally, the application will have been packaged with the necessary libraries that will allow for it to connect to the SQL Server and database instance set up by your IT. You don't need any SQL Server Standard edition installed on the client's machine as your client would not be developing anything further.

Comment: I don't have the application ready, so I cannot do a test on a client's machine. IT set up an instance of SQL Server for me and I can connect using Visual Studio SQL Server Object Explorer or SSMS. So, I don’t have a problem on my developer computer. The question is, what will happen when I try to deploy the application. It looks like I don't need to add any specific packages or redistributables. This is great news. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched the net and a similar question has been asked many times, but I didn’t find a clear answer before. Many people started their SQL Server experience using local type databases, like SQL Server CE or LocalDB. In this case specific DLLs and redistributables must be added with the installation program. It is hard to understand at the beginning, but when an instance of SQL Server is on a remote server, this is a different story. Everything is happening on this remote server. There is no need of any SQL Server instances on a client’s machine. Just a connection string must be added. The adapter or Entity Framework will take care of everything else.